# Editable-bsDate="" Set options

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have a problem with the following code. 
I need to style it with the option: datepickerMode: 'year'
It went fine in other fields i have where it is a editable text box, however this is a href that turns into editable when clicked. I have had no luck with the data-e-datepicker-options="my options in scope"

```
<a href="#"
  editable-bsdate="target"
  data-e-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"
  data-e-ng-click="open($event,'date')"
  data-e-is-open="opened.date"
  onbeforesave="callback($data)" >
  {{ (target | date:"dd-MM-yyyy") || placeholder }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
e-datepicker-mode="'year'"
```